# Modify Output of Image Field During Display

Tags: webforms

This is on a webform based (not MVC based ) solution. I want to change a content / adding additional mark up (let us say add additional attribute in as Image element )in the sub layout at runtime for every request based on some condition. What would be right place to extend this logic ?

for example

This is there in the sublayout

```
<Img src='<source of the image>'>
```

In other scenario , I would like to modify this element to

```
<Img Data-Src='<source of the image>'>
```

This i want to achieve this at runtime for every request

Comment: Can you add an example of your markup today and what kind of data you want to add?

Comment: data-src is the attribute

Comment: Can you show some example markup in your question and give an example of what you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to modify the output of a particular field, your best bet is to override the `renderField` processor of the field type you're targeting.

```
<renderField>
  ...
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

#### Create a new class that inherits from the existing class:

```
public class CustomGetImageFieldValue : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue
{

}
```

#### Then override the `SetRenderFieldResult` method:

```
public class CustomGetImageFieldValue : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue
{
  protected override void SetRenderFieldResult(RenderFieldResult result, RenderFieldArgs args)
  {
    args.Result.FirstPart = result.FirstPart; // set a breakpoint and see if this contains the markup you want to target
    args.Result.LastPart = result.LastPart; // set a breakpoint and see if this contains the markup you want to target
    args.WebEditParameters.AddRange((SafeDictionary<string, string>) args.Parameters);
    args.DisableWebEditContentEditing = true;
    args.DisableWebEditFieldWrapping = true;
    args.WebEditClick = "return Sitecore.WebEdit.editControl($JavascriptParameters, 'webedit:chooseimage')";
  }
}
```

**Note: You will need to check whether `FirstPart` or `LastPart` has the content you're targeting. Make modifications and save it to the `args.Result` object. As always, add proper conditions, exit early, etc.**

#### Patch in changes:

```
<renderField>
  <processor patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Custom.CustomGetImageFieldValue , Custom" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail . Unfortunately , my Sitecore version is  8.2 Initial release and i don't see  SetRenderFieldResult method to be overridden . but the other version of sitecore (Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170728)) has this method . How do we then achieve this in intial release ? do we have any patch available to address this ?